# How to Select Multiple Value in Autocomplete in CodeIgniter using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How to take multiple value when autocomplete with ajax in codeignator

view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="search">

  <div id="result"></div>
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#search").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin/ajaxPro",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossOrigin: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                search: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {

        $("#result").append(
            "<div>" + ui.item.value + "</div>"

        );

    },
});
```

});

controller

```
 public function ajaxPro()
        {
          
            $term = $this->input->get('term');
    
            // var_dump($term);
    
            $this->db->like('business_name', $term);
     
            $resultSet = $this->db->get("user_table")->result();
            $data = [];
            foreach($resultSet as $rs){
                $data[] = $rs->business_name;

            }
            
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

When I retrieve data using autocomplete, the only business_name is attached to the select: function Only the business name is available in the item .value, how do you get the corresponding value of the business name?

[Please check the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmZ9D.jpg)

Now if I select the business name, how do I append the Email and rating in the result?

Comment: Use something like this :
`$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get()->result_array();`

Comment: How does the controller add this query?

Comment: please help me ,Nobody knows what to do and how

Comment: let me know, what is the requirement?